# Closed question about visual programming paradigms

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

I had a question closed today, [Why did visual programming never take off and what future paradigms might change that?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119463/why-did-visual-programming-never-take-off-and-what-future-paradigms-might-change) which I do not understandy why. People keep responding the question, and for me the explanation for the closing makes no sense at all. Actually all the answers were very useful for me, and most of them were based on facts and based on each one knowledge. So I'd like to ask for reopen the question.

Comment: Regarding the close... It depends, usually a close means that something is wrong with your question, and that it doesn't comply to the rules of the P.SE FAQ. Yours seems to be "protected" now, which is usually what the mods for your own good: if a question is popular and generates too much interest, they use this after enough good answers have been posted to limit the entry of new non-constructive questions that attempt to piggy-back on the question's success, or that will most likely repeat things already said and lost in the noise.

Comment: Well, now I cannot even access the question to edit and try to improve. I guess this title "Why did visual programming never take off and what future paradigms might change that?" gets the whole idea wrong from my original question. First I wanted to know which are the new visual programming paradigms, so I expected things like "There is X new programming paradigms. The first is (...) and represents (...), the second is ......" and so on, but this is exactly what I got from the answers! But now it's closed and I cannot read it anymore.

Comment: And now when I click on the question, it appears to me "Your question was removed from Programmers - Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation", which appears to me more obscure than the last given reason.

Comment: @Rego The deletion was weird, there's no information on who deleted the question. I _think_ it was deleted automatically as it was asked back in November, but it doesn't really matter I've just undeleted it.

Answer (score 4):

Well the close reason says it all:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Stack Exchange isn't the right place for a discussion or argument. This doesn't mean that the question isn't interesting or of interest to programmers, just that it doesn't fit the Stack Exchange model.

However:

> If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Comment: Actually I had asked about if there exist some new visual programming paradigms, and if so, what methodologies they use. It seems to me very objective, since I hoped for answers like "yes, there is a methodology called bla,..." or "I've never been heard about it". But someone edited the title, and before I could revert it, the question was closed. But I really did not expect for a discussion.

Answer (score 2):

So let's run through the [good question checklist](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

- Do your homework
  I give you a grade of C on this one.  Yes, you pulled together the context, but you didn't cite any references. Your question didn't show any real level of research effort.
- Be specific
  Here you missed big time.  You asked two very big-answer questions.

One of which is difficult to prove.

```
Why did visual programming never take off
```

The second of which is almost unanswerable.

```
So, how advanced should be the "new" visual programming languages paradigms? 
Which characteristics these new paradigms would be required?
```

Guessing at the future is fun, but it's not on-topic for P.SE.

- Make it relevant to others
  Definitely a programming related question, and kind of an interesting one too.  A+.
- Be on-topic
  Another D or F here for the same reasons as in item 2 - Be Specific.
- Keep an open mind
  I'm giving you a D or a C here because I don't currently see any comments / replies from you in that question.

So why did it get closed?  Take a deep look into #2 and #4.  You have asked interesting, but essentially unanswerable questions.  Unanswerable questions don't belong in a Q&A format no matter how interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer, but didn't fit in a comment. Lots of strange things happened to the question as it was originally migrated here from Stack Overflow and when it was closed, it was also locked. That's supposed to happen with rejected migrations, however rejected migrations aren't supposed to survive that long (asked Nov 13 '11), and while locked, the question couldn't be edited.

The Stack Overflow version of the question was deleted, so I cleared the migration history, to unlock the question and untie it from Stack Overflow, but that also re-opened the question automatically, and since this was originally a community closure, I closed it again. If re-opened, it should be re-opened by five votes, and not by a dumb side-effect of clearing its migration path.

On top of everything else, the question was automatically deleted, being an old closed question, apparently the fact that it was only closed fairly recently didn't really matter. I've un-deleted it, and now it's finally where it should be: closed and unlocked, ready to be improved, and possibly re-opened.

Check the [question's revisions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/119463/revisions) to see its history.

Answer (score 1):

You committed two big sins here:

1. You asked more than one question.
2. Your second question solicited debate.

If you did neither of those, the <strike>moderators</strike> community probably would have left your question alone.

Comment: The question was closed by five regular users, no moderators involved (well, other than me, doing some mod magic, [check my answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3766/25936))